# How to generate Javadoc for Maven Central?

Tags: gradle, javadoc, bintray

I am trying to sync my package from bintray with Maven Central, but get this error :

[image]

What do I need to do to generate the Javadoc?

I use the Gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'
    }
```

Comment: You might want to add 'gradle' tag and remove 'maven' as this is a gradle issue.

Answer (score 0):

**In Maven:**

According to [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/), you should add the `javadoc` plugin:

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
        <configuration>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```

And then run `mvn site`.

---

**In Gradle:**

According to [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html), you should add a task of type `Javadoc` and then add the output of this task to a `configuration` or a `publication`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task myJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
  source = sourceSets.main.allJava
}
```

You can find complete examples of Gradle projects that publish to Bintray's JCenter at [Bintray's examples project on GitHub](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples/tree/master/gradle-example).

Comment: Where should I insert this text ?

Comment: Don't you think that it might be important piece of information to add to the question then?!

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry, i added additional information in question

Comment: Baruch, I use this plugin https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release. Please tell me where I should insert the code you gave me